# How to safely stop/start my postgres server when using docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker

I sometimes stop/start docker very often when I am release new features in my application.

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose stop
```

I am using pretty much the bare bones postgres docker setup (see below).
I am mapping the /data folder to my host.

Is there anything I should be worried about if I stop/start docker many times in a day in terms of data getting corrupted?

Is calling `docker-compose stop` the best way to be stopping my postgres instance?

My postgres service in my docker-compose looks like this:

```
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - "/home/deploy/data/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    restart: always
```

This setup currently is running smoothly in development, but once it goes to production I want to make sure I am following best practices etc.

Answer (score 5):

Use,

```
docker-compose down -v
```

What it does is basically removes all the volumes you added. If you don't those volumes will hang on and eat up your space. It only removes the volume inside the docker container. The volume in your host stays and survives container removal in case if you want that data to survive container removal.

Whenever you create a docker container by `docker run`, Docker creates a volume/ directory to keep the details about the containers. After you execute `docker run`, if you look into `/var/lib/docker/containers`, you will see one directory for each container you started. If you have not removed the volumes for previous container, you will see many directories under the "container" directory. The name of these directories will be very long random letters and number. So, if you don't tell the docker to remove these directories when you stop the container, it will be there forever. The `v` option I mentioned above, will delete these directories when you take down the container. 
Keep in mind, you can view the contents of the directory `/var/lib/docker` only as a root user. To change to root user, use `sudo -i` before you attempt to view the contents of the directory.

Comment: so what do you mean?  if I do ```stop``` how will can I tell if those volumes are still lingering around?  Sorry just don't understand "hang on and eat up your space" means, is there a docker commadn where I can see them lingering?

Comment: ```Total reclaimed space: 24.48GB``` thanks for the tip!

Comment: Wasn't the question how to stop PostgreSQL cleanly?

Answer (score 4):

Databases in particular are usually designed so that it's very hard to lose data, even if the machine loses power in the middle of writing something to disk.  (This comes at some performance cost.)  So long as you don't have more than one PostgreSQL instance at a time using the same backing data store, I'd expect it to not lose data or otherwise corrupt itself; the worst you should expect to see is a message at startup that it's recovering from a write-ahead log or something along those lines.

[docker stop](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) will send a signal to a container that prompts it to shut down cleanly, and PostgreSQL will take this as a cue to shut down.  It looks like [docker-compose stop](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/stop/), [docker-compose down](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/), and sending ^C to [docker-compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) all use the same mechanism.  So the way you're doing it now should result in a clean shutdown (provided PostgreSQL finishes its cleanup within 10 seconds).

I believe you can [docker-compose restart](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/restart/) specific services, or [docker-compose up --force-recreate](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) them.  This would help if you rebuilt your application container and needed to restart that, but not its database.

Comment: `docker stop` is documented to send SIGTERM, wait 10 seconds, then send SIGKILL; the procedure in the question is correct.  I added a paragraph to my answer explaining this.